# The past tense of eat: eat or ate

Tags: morphology

It seems that the past tense of *eat* is both *eat* and *ate.* (OED.)
I think *ate* is more prevalent.  Is *eat* used in a certain region?

> eat
>
> ▪ I. eat, v. 
>   (iːt)
>   pa. tense ate, eat (eɪt, ɛt, iːt). pa. pple. eaten (ˈiːt(ə)n).

Comment: Please quote the entry in its entirety, and better still, supply a link.

Comment: The OED is the official Oxford English Dictionary whose [annual subscription](https://public.oed.com/help/how-to-subscribe/) is about £95 until December 2019. If you have a library card you are allowed free access.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, what happens in December?

Comment: It reverts to its original price. Can you please cite the relevant part which says that "eat" is also the past tense?

Comment: @Mari-LouA, all right, did it.  What's the original price?

Comment: Click on the link? That excerpt doesn't come directly from the OED, it's too brief.  Did you find it here?: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Language/2017_January_25#past_tense_of_'to_eat'

Comment: @Mari-LouA, oh.  Best to have a library card.

Comment: *The OED, under "forms" says " pa. tenseOE–ME æt, (ME æat), ME et(t, ME–15 ete, ME at, (ME hete), ME eet(te, 15–16 eate, **16–18 eat**, 15– ate". ***So it acknowledges past "eat" up to the 18th century, but not 19th***.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, but couldn't this mean that in the 18th c. eat was the only form, and that later there were two forms?

Comment: I am not sure how this is a morphology question.

Comment: @EddieKal Morphology is a very general term; it is "the branch of grammar which studies the structure or forms of words [...]" (*A Dictionary of Linguistics and Phonetics, 6th ed.*, p.314).  This includes *inflection*, which in turn includes what was traditionally called *conjugation* (the inflection of verbs, i.e. the various forms that verbs can take).  On this site we tend to put these questions under [tag:conjugations], which is more specific, but [tag:morphology] isn't *wrong*, just not quite as specific as we might like.

Comment: @snailcar That did cross my mind, but I just felt it'd be a stretch to include all spelling questions under morphology. I also voted to close because I find the question lacking on the source/context/research side.

Comment: @EddieKal I didn't take it as a question about *spelling*, but rather about the range of preterite forms of *eat* in Present Day English (discussion of which can cover but is not limited to spelling).

Answer (score 3):

The past tense of "eat" is "ate" and nothing else in standard modern English.

The pronunciation of "ate" varies from dialect to dialect.  For many it is "eit" for others (especially  British RP speakers) it is "et".

In archaic and historic English there have been various other past tense form. The OED doesn't document just Current English, but historic English over the past 1000 years.

Comment: it would be useful to add something about how archaic it is.  when was it last used in literature?

Comment: I don't see any relevance. If it was used 100, 200, 500 years ago. It is not used now.

Comment: I thought eit = ate and et = eat.    are you saying the preterite eat was pronounced exactly like the present?